# ballast replaced and only 2 iod 4 fluorescent lights work

Tags: wiring

**I replaced the ballast and only 2 of the 4 bulbs light up. I took one of the bulbs out and the other two lit up and the original 2 went out.

What's going on?**

Comment: What are the model numbers of the old and new ballasts? Many ballasts have a wiring diagram printed on them, if yours do can you add pictures?

Comment: Old ballast is a 496-AT. New ballast is a KTSB-E-1232-24-UV-S-IP

Comment: How many feet of bulbs do you have? Are they T8 or T12?

Comment: Is the fixture grounded?

Comment: 32 feet of T12. Ballast grounded through mounting screw

Comment: It's likely either have a loose connection or a bad ballast.

Comment: Loose wire, or a wire jarred out of a lamp holder during installation, or the problem was never the ballast in the first place. Wire or lamp holder deterioration from being outdoors?  I don't deal much in sign lighting but the wiring diagrams and wire colors are identical.  Keystone is a reputable brand.